# Given operator $\hat{L}_z = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}$, find the operators $\hat{L}_x$, $\hat{L}_y$, $\hat{L}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, mathematical-physics

I'm working on the following problem in my quantum mechanics course:

> Consider the following matrix form of the angular momentum operator for a system with $l=1$: $$\hat{L}_z = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$
>   **1)** Is this operator Hermetian, unitary, a projection operator?
>
> **2)** Give the operators $\hat{L}_x$, $\hat{L}_y$ and calculate $\hat{L}^2$ in matrix form.

My solution to **part 1:**
$\hat{L}_z$ is hermitian if and only if $\hat{L}_z=\hat{L}_z^H$. This is clearly the case (real diagonal, zero everywhere else). Unitary if and only if $\hat{L}_z^*\hat{L}_z = \hat{L}_z\hat{L}_z^*=I_3$, but $\hat{L}_z^*\hat{L}_z\neq I_3$ (Middle $0$ remains as is.) A projection operator if and only if $\hat{L}_z^2=\hat{L}_z$ which is also clearly not the case here.

But I'm not sure how I can use this knowledge (Hermitian but not unitary or a projection) to find $\hat{L}_x, \hat{L}_y$.

Comment: There is no information from which to derive the other matrices. Clearly the question is relying on some kind of prior knowledge. That prior knowledge may as well be the matrices themselves. My point being: what are we allowed to assume? You haven't specified.

Comment: @Myridium This is literally the entire question. The commutation relations are considered are considered known. But aside from that, there's really nothing else.

Comment: What commutation relations? I don't think it's reasonable to post a question like this on MSE and assume this kind of background knowledge. On Physics.SE, fair enough.

Comment: Physics.SE has a rule against problems. Hence the Mathematical physics tag. The commutation relations can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_operator#Commutation_relations They're used for verification, not derivation. But as Spencer pointed out below, it's basically just guess work to find the right ones.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are given that $L_x$, $L_y$ and $L_z$ should follow the angular momentum algebra, that is,
$$[L_i,L_j]=\mathrm i\epsilon_{ijk}L_k \tag{1}$$
Now from this alone, the $L_x$ and $L_y$ are not uniquely defined.

From $(1)$ we get $L_y=\mathrm i[L_x,L_z]$.
Let's for the moment write
$$L_x=\pmatrix{a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&j} \tag{2}$$
where by assumption all numbers are real. Then we get:
$$L_y = \pmatrix{0 & -\mathrm ib & -2\mathrm i c\\
\mathrm id & 0 & -\mathrm if\\
2\mathrm ig & \mathrm ih  & 0}$$
Now again using $(1)$, we have $L_x = i[L_z, L_y]$, so inserting our previous result, we get
$$L_x = \pmatrix{0 & b & 4c\\ d & 0 & f\\ 4g & h & 0} \tag{3}$$
Now comparing eqs. $(2)$ and $(3)$, we find that $a=c=e=g=j=0$.
Finally we use $(1)$ again in the instance $[L_x,L_y] = \mathrm iL_z$. This gives
$$\pmatrix{\mathrm ibd & 0 & -\mathrm ibf\\
0 & \mathrm i(-db + fh) & 0\\
\mathrm ihd & 0 & -\mathrm ihf}
 - \pmatrix{-\mathrm ibd & 0 & -\mathrm ibf\\
0 & \mathrm i(bd-hf) & 0\\
\mathrm idh & 0 & \mathrm ifh}
 = \pmatrix{\mathrm i & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -\mathrm i}$$
From this we can conclude that
$$bd=hf=\frac12 \tag{4}$$

To go further, we need another condition: Namely that like $L_z$, also $L_x$ and $L_y$ should be Hermitean. Thus $d=b^*$ and $h=f^*$. Then $(4)$ reduces to $|b|^2=|f|^2=\frac12$. Writing
$$b = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\phi}, f = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\chi}$$
we get
$$L_x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{0 & \mathrm e^{\mathrm i\phi} & 0\\
\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i\phi} & 0 & \mathrm e^{\mathrm i\chi} \\
0 & \mathrm e^{-i\chi} & 0},\quad
L_y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{0 & -\mathrm i\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\phi} & 0\\
\mathrm i\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i\phi} & 0 & -\mathrm i\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i\chi} \\
0 & \mathrm i\mathrm e^{i\chi} & 0}
$$
Now let's calculate $L^2 = L_x^2 + L_y^2 + L_z^2$. This gives
$$L^2 = \pmatrix{2 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 2} = 2I$$
where $I$ is the $3\times 3$ unit matrix.

The usual representation is obtained by choosing $\phi=\chi=0$. This results in $L_x$ only having real entries, and $L_y$ only having imaginary entries.

Actually I'm surprised that you apparently cannot derive $\phi=\chi$ (one free angle can be physically explained by the fact that fixing only the $z$ axis still allows rotations in the $x$-$y$ plane; however I don't know what I should make of the second angle).